# GTM Multiple sessions in 30 min interval using AngularJS

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, turbolinks, event-tracking

On of our products has been built using Angular.js.  All tracking tags, including Google Analytics, are fired through a GTM container. We are using Turbolinks, so page changes within the site are loaded via ajax, although the URL does change. It's not strictly a Single Page Application, but we do use a virtual pageview event in GTM instead of a regular trigger.

Analyzing user paths on BigQuery revealed that we have an issue with session continuity, whereby users who trigger an event in the middle of a chain of pageviews will be treated by GA as being 2-3 distinct sessions, even though they occur within a 30 minute window.

How can we prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a Session shouldn't timeout for 30 minutes, but there are actually three reasons why a User's Session can come to an end.

- They didn't interact for more than the Session Timeout time (This is usually 30 minutes).
- They passed midnight (this is just to keep things tidy).
- Their Source changes (so, for example, they navigate to your site by Google and by Facebook in the same Session).

Any of these could be causing your issue. I recommend you do the following:

- Check that no-one has edited the Session Timeout setting.
- Ensure midnight is defined in a sensible place for your site, and isn't near the Sessions that you're worried about.
- Inspect these Sessions' Source field, to see if and why it changed. You may find that you issue is an inadvertently campaign tagged internal link.

For more information:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565